# Pointers and Classes in Python 3

Tags: python

I have a class in Python 3.  I am using look-ahead operations on it, and therefore need to create a new object of the class identical to me current instance so the current object does not get changed.

I currently have this code:

```
board_copy = Board()
board_copy.data = [x[:] for x in self.data]
```

This is creating a pointer to the original data, rather than copying it; therefore, the data is being modified anyway.  I tried this:

```
import copy

board_copy = copy.deepcopy(self.data)
```

I now get this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'deep_copy'

I did many searches and was able to get this far because of former SO posts and the Python documentation, but I cannot find this a solution for this specific problem anywhere.  Any tips will be welcome.

Comment: It should be `copy.deepcopy`.

Comment: @GregEnnis Yes.  So sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might as well make this an answer then for any future visitors to this page.

The function you want is [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), not `copy.deep_copy`:

```
>>> import copy
>>> copy.deepcopy
<function deepcopy at 0x01BAEE30>
>>>
```